# Insert one row using different models/pages - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to **CodeIgniter** and I'm building a simple I/O website. I have only one database, say `test` and only one table `results`, that looks like this:

**screenshot of the table "results"**

[image]

I have two views `personal.php` and `songs.php`. In the first one I collect the data values to be inserted into the fields 2,3, and 4, and the rest of the values are collected in the second view. They are then inserted into the table via their relevant models, `personal_model` and `songs_model`.
Now obviously, they will be inserted into 2 different rows which is not what I want. What is the trick here? How should I manage it? So far I have thought of getting the last ID but I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance!

`personal.php` (first view)

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('data/personal'); ?> //passes the data to the controller that loads the personal_model.php
"some input fields"
<button  type="submit" name="submit">Submit Data</button>
```

`songs.php` (second view)

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('data/songs'); ?> //passes the data to the controller that loads the songs_model.php
"some input fields"
<button  type="submit" name="submit">Submit Rating</button>
```

`personal_model.php` (first model)

```
<?php
class Personal_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function insert_personal()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $data = array(
            'age' => $this->input->post('user_age'),
            'education' => $this->input->post('user_edu'),
            'twitter' => $this->input->post('user_twitter'),
            'facebook' => $this->input->post('user_facebook')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('results', $data); 
    }   
}
```

`songs_model.php` (second model)

```
<?php
class Ratings_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function insert_ratings()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        #$this->load->database();
        $data = array(
            'score' => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'song1' => $this->input->post('rnd1'),
            'song2' => $this->input->post('rnd2') 
        );

        return $this->db->insert('results', $data);     
    }
}
```

Comment: This is some thing like Parent-Child. it means according to your question `personal.php` is parent and `songs.php` is child. So insert first Parent data and save it then load it Child view with ID of the parent. Hope its helps

Comment: You don't need to have two models since you are doing the same thing (inserting row) in both files.  You'd be better off passing data from your controller to your model, in your model have `public function insert_data($data)` and build your arrays in your controller, not in your model.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Thanks a lot! It gave me some insight.

Comment: @Dan Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller Function should be like this.

```
public function personal()
    {
        $lastInsertedID = $this->Personal_model->insert_personal();
        $this->session->set_userdata("personalID",$lastInsertedID);
    }
```

Set the last inserted id into session in your above controller function which should be return from your Personal_model. Here is code.

```
public function insert_personal()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $data = array(
        'age' => $this->input->post('user_age'),
        'education' => $this->input->post('user_edu'),
        'twitter' => $this->input->post('user_twitter'),
        'facebook' => $this->input->post('user_facebook')
    );

    $this->db->insert('results', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Then update your existing row in your insert_ratings function instead of insert record. Here is code.

```
public function insert_ratings()
    {
        $data = array(
            'score' => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'song1' => $this->input->post('rnd1'),
            'song2' => $this->input->post('rnd2') 
        );
        $personalID = $this->session->userdata("personalID");
        $this->db->where("id",$personalID);
        $this->db->update('results', $data); 
        return $this->db->affected_rows();    
    }
```

Then no new record will insert into table while submit your song.php form it will update the existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the basic idea is that I have to keep track of unique value (ID or IP) of a user so that I can update the row instead of inserting a new one. Now I'm familiarizing myself with the session class in CI. I think I can make it to work. If I find an issue I will comment here again!

Comment: Great! Yes, you can comment any time. If this did help you, don't forget to accept this answer. Cheers!

Comment: It certainly did help! Merry Christmas and thanks again!